# Как получить единичный вектор?

Tags: python, математика, геометрия

Имеется вектор AB на плоскости, мы знаем его координаты. Нам необходимо вычислить единичный вектор. Предположим, что это координаты A (1, 1), B (5, 6).

Comment: Поделить разности `x_B-x_A` и `y_B-y_A` на длину вектора. Для предположим это вектор `(4/sqrt(41),5/sqrt(41))`.

Comment: @Harry, благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: поскольку]

отсюда

```
size = ((b[0] - a[0])**2 + (b[1] - a[1])**2)**0.5

c = ((b[0] - a[0]) / size, (b[1] - a[1]) / size)
```